# What is the PHPDoc Eclipse multitype: and how do I use it?

Tags: phpdoc, eclipse-pdt, type-hinting, php-ide

When I document my methods in PDT Eclipse, if the return of a method might be an array, it generates the following kind of documentation / type hinting:
* @return multitype:Ambigous <\CodeBase\Node\DataNode, NULL>

I have looked for this documentation and found a few good ones, but nothing good on the "multitype" and "Ambiguous".

Is there any documentation which covers how to best make use of this in order to use the type hinting? Is it maybe possible to define the array structure returned: e.g. that the returned array contains a string key and a certain kind of object - would be useful for "foreach" loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDT since 3.6 (Mars.1) no longer generate multitype / amiguous and follow phpdoc standard:

multitype:ClassName => ClassName[]

Amiguous< ClassName,ClassName2 > => ClassName|ClassName2

See also:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467148
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467151